# JPA, CMP and BMP

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I am a .NET Developer.  I studied Java and specifically [J2EE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) at university in 2003.

I learnt terms such as *Container Managed Persistence* (CMP) and *Bean Managed Persistence* (BMP).

According to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API), the *Java Persistence API* has replaced CMP.  I guess that Bean Managed Persistence is still a term in use.

➥ Is that correct or has something replaced BMP as a term?

I understand that [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) is an [ORM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like Entity Framework in [.NET](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).  You use JPA for simple applications (with simple [SQL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)) and Bean Managed Persistence for complex SQL.

➥ Is that correct or is there something available for complex SQL (with many joins) - perhaps similar to [LINQ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) from .NET?

Comment: BMP is in the grave right next to CMP. JPA fully supports complex queries with multiple joins.

Comment: It's worth to mention JPQL and Criteria API which are both part of the JPA spec. Beside that you have *Container Managed vs Bean Managed **Transactions***.

Comment: @SteveC Could you make an Answer of your comment, so this Question might be closed?

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque.

Answer (score 1):

BMP and CMP have been considered legacy technologies since JPA was introduced into the Java EE 5 specifications in 2006.

They became optional in Java EE implementations with the release of the EJB 3.2 specification that is associated with Java EE 7.

You are correct that JPA is an ORM framework. It fully supports complex queries with multiple joins using the SQL like JPQL language, as well as "native" queries where absolutely needed.  Furthermore, it is possible to compose fully type safe queries on the fly in Java using the Criteria API.

Comment: See also this nice brief history in [this WikiBooks page](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_JPA%3F) about “What is JPA?”